# How to count distinct values from a whole column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Column A: CASE ID; Column B: Fruit.

How many distinct cases are there under "Apple"

How do I distinct count a whole column if the cell value match one criteria without using pivot tables?

Here are the 2 solutions I tried but they don't work when I select whole column :

solution 1:

```
{SUM(((B2:B13="Apple"))/COUNTIFS(B2:B13,B2:B13,A2:A13,A2:A13))}
```

solution 2:

```
{SUM(IF(B2:B13="Apple",1/(COUNTIFS(B2:B13,"Apple",A2:A13,A2:A13)),0))}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When using array formulas, whole column references are extremely inefficient.  In your case, it's likely that Excel simply runs out of resources and either returns 0 or displays an error message stating that Excel has run out of resources.

Comment: Instead of using whole column references, convert your data into a Table so that the ranges automatically adjust as data is added/removed.  Or use dynamic defined names.

Answer (score 1):

Given no version constraints, as per your tags, the following will present the unique counts:

*Note that I used a **Table**  with structured references so no need to consider whole-columns*

```
=HSTACK(
    UNIQUE(Fruits[Fruit]),
    BYROW(
        UNIQUE(Fruits[Fruit]),
        LAMBDA(arr,
            ROWS(
                FILTER(
                    UNIQUE(Fruits),
                    TAKE(UNIQUE(Fruits), , -1) = arr
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

Or, if you want to include column Headers in your results:

```
=VSTACK(
    {"Fruit", "Distinct Count"},
    HSTACK(
        UNIQUE(Fruits[Fruit]),
        BYROW(
            UNIQUE(Fruits[Fruit]),
            LAMBDA(arr,
                ROWS(
                    FILTER(
                        UNIQUE(Fruits),
                        TAKE(UNIQUE(Fruits), , -1) = arr
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNTIFS` as follows, *assuming no Excel version constraints as per the tag listed in the question*:

```
=LET(A, A2:A12, B,B2:B12, ux,UNIQUE(B), VSTACK({"Fruit","Distinct Count"}, 
 HSTACK(ux,BYROW(COUNTIFS(B,ux,A,TOROW(UNIQUE(A))), LAMBDA(x,SUM(N(x>0)))))))
```

The output of `COUNTIFS`, counts the number of CASE ID unique values per unique Fruit, where the rows represent the unique Fruits values (`4`) and the columns (`7`), the number of unique CASE ID. Therefore the element `i`,`j` of `COUNTIFS` output, represents the count for row `j` of `UNIQUE(A)` for the fruit in row `i` of `UNIQUE(B)`.

You can use `MMULT` instead of `BYROW` as follows:

```
=LET(A,A2:A12, B,B2:B12, uxA,UNIQUE(A), uxB,UNIQUE(B),
 VSTACK({"Fruit","Distinct Count"}, HSTACK(uxB, 
 MMULT(N(COUNTIFS(B,uxB,A,TOROW(uxA))>0),SEQUENCE(ROWS(uxA),,,0)))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]